# Remove Unused Keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I would like to be able to clean unused keyframes from my dope sheet, ones that aren't doing anything.

I read online that you press 'O' in the dope sheet to do this, but I tried it and it didn't work. So, I looked for the hotkey and preferences, and it isn't there!

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I do believe pressing <kbd>O</kbd> used to run this tool in the Dope Sheet, but for consistency with the other editors <kbd>O</kbd> now seems to enable proportional editing. Now the 'Clean Keyframes' option resides in the *Key> Clean Keyframes* menu.

[image]

*WARNING* This will reset ALL interpolation back to the F-Curve default Interpolation.

Comment: I found that right away and tried it, but it doesn't delete the keyframes :P Apparently it just removes closely spaced keyframes to simplify the curves.

Comment: Hey I found it! Just press delete and select "Clean Channels"

Comment: I couldn't find a 'Clean Channels' option in 2.75, I only found that the same 'Clean keyframes' tool I mentioned is also displayed in the 'delete' menu.

Answer (score 0):

'Clean keyframes' is designed to do this task for you. However, it will destroy work you put into applying and editing interpolation settings.

The safest way to remove unused keyframes is to open up the F-Curve editor, zoom in with the ctrl and middle mouse button and select keyframes that are zeroed those are the ones that are zeroed. You may want to leave some if you animation requires it.

Unfortunately, this method won't help you if you have posed a character and keyed the same pose multiple times.